# Monotouch NSTextStorage implementation how to

Tags: xamarin.ios, nstextstorage

I'm trying to port some objective c codes to c#
header file contains

```
@interface MyStorage : NSTextStorage
@end
```

and implementation is something like

```
#import "MyStorage .h"
@interface MyStorage ()
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSMutableAttributedString *myAttrString;
- (id)init
{
    if (self = [super init]) {

        _myAttrString= [NSMutableAttributedString new];

    }
    return self;
}
- (NSString *)string
{
    return [_myAttrString string];
}
```

but i can not understand the

```
- (NSString *)string
{
    return [_myAttrString string];
}
```

part. It's a abstract property or something like that i think, but i do not know how to override it on c#, does anybody know what is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thnks for your reply Larry, but i found it as i search for overridable methods and properties,
it is:

```
public override IntPtr LowLevelValue {
            get {
                return _myAttrString.LowLevelValue;
            }
        }
```

so if you take some abstraction errors on runtime, just keep on looking overridable methods and properties :)

Answer (score 1):

The `NSAttributedString.Value` property holds the string's text content. Is that what you're looking for?